# css dropdown options on hover

Tags: html, css

Ive been try to create a link where you can hover over it and show a list of links/options.  Ive kind of got it working in firefox and google chrome, but wont display at all in internet explorer when i hover over the link.

I also have a problem in firefox and google where I want to set the bottom border of the link to match the list of options background color so the menu merges together, but I cant get the z-index to display the link on top.

Ive put all my css and html code on the following page  for you to see:

http://www.usedcar.co.uk/drop.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, for list-based menus:

- Don't style the `LI`, put all styling on the `A`-tag and give it `display:block`.
- Put the hover on the `A`-tag, not the `LI`